# Google Maps App: Hosting .js Files on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drive

I've found a few older links with tips to host .js files on Google Drive.  It appears that the correct method has changed over time; I cannot get my Google Maps app to see the required references when hosted.  Map app works fine when .js files are local.

Guessing its simple, just need to know the correct approach.

Here's where I am at:

```
1.  Created a shared folder on Google Drive
2.  Uploaded, then shared the 2 .js files
3.  Grabbed the shared file link and inserted into the reference, example:
    Replaced:  <script type="text/javascript" src="labels.js"></script>
    With:  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=<my id here></script>
No luck
4.  I tried using just the shared folder ID, and appended the "/labels.js" filename
Also No luck
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more poking around and an assist from a friend, the following form seems to be working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="my_doc_id"</script>
```

Comment: you're missing a quotation marks and '>' after "my_doc_id" .

Should be:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="my_doc_id""></script>